# How to push information to all users from many horizontal EC2 servers?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, horizontal-scaling

One of the requirements of my app is that when one user makes any insert/update/delete, all users viewing a page with a list of that record type get pushed an update containing the change. The user should not be expected to repeat an API call to refresh the dozens of records that did not change, because the push should contain a short summary of the change that occurred.

I accomplished this in my small dev server using SocketIO. I can't scale this across more than one server. My target infrastructure is AWS, and I know AWS has a push notification service, but I believe it's mobile-only and not what I'm looking for. The huge number of data streams being subscribed to is the reason I haven't consider a server-less infrastructure.

I'm new to AWS and have never attempted horizontal scaling either, so please forgive me if my entire question is ignorant.

Comment: Have you taken a look at using AWS IoT MQTT messaging protocol? Each browser is a 'device' and you have javascript listening in the browser for messages published via a socket protocol. Each service pushes a message to MQTT when it has an update. There's some good POCs out there (i.e. https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357)

Comment: @ChrisPollard The marketing for the service gave me no inclination that it was useful for browsers. It looked like something oriented solely towards IoT. Thank you for pointing this out to me! At first glance, this might be what I'm looking for. Between this and API Gateway I might even be able to go serverless.

Comment: It's a really creative use of the service, I've done some really cool stuff using Lambda/API Gateway/Dynamodb + this pattern + S3 buckets with java script web pages for a completely serverless yet interactive experience.

Comment: @ChrisPollard You should repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it! You gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at using AWS IoT MQTT messaging protocol? Each browser is a 'device' and you have javascript listening in the browser for messages published via a socket protocol. Each service pushes a message to MQTT when it has an update. There's some good POCs out there (i.e. medium.com/@jparreira/…)